# Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
    public class LoginActivityTest {

        @InjectMocks
        LoginActivity loginActivity;

        private Pattern emailPattern;

        @Before
        public void createLogin(){
            this.emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        }

        @Test
        public void checkValidation(){
            mock(LoginActivity.class);
            UserVO userVO = new UserVO();
            userVO.setEmailID("invalid");
            userVO.setPassword("a");

            boolean b = loginActivity.validatesFields(userVO);

            assertFalse(b);

        }
    }
```

this.emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; This is creating null pointer object in MockitoJunitTestClass. But, when I run this on Activity it gets initialized properly.

Comment: it would be really nice if we have `LoginActivity` code on the example.

Answer (score 9):

Use PatternsCompat instead of Patterns

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem because it was just a simple test, but when I added `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` the problem was fixed. Check if this is test that must run with Android resources or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confuse with your test:

You are mocking `LoginActivity.class` but not setting anything with that. I believe you want to do something like `loginActivity = mock(LoginActivity.class);` instead.

Also, your are mocking instead spying the class, so it won't access the real method in order to verify the flow of this method. In other words, your test is doing nothing in fact.

Finally, this `emailPattern` is never used on your test (probably it is used on you code), so I believe you want to mock it (I am supposing it). What I recommend you do is something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private LoginActivity loginActivity;

    @Mock
    private OtherStuff otherStuff;

    @Test
    public void checkValidation(){
        UserVO userVO = new UserVO();
        userVO.setEmailID("invalid");
        userVO.setPassword("a");

        doReturn(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS).when(otherStuff).doStuff();

        boolean result = loginActivity.validatesFields(userVO);

        assertFalse(result);
    }
}
```

What I did here is just an example of unit test which is validating what `validateFields()` is doing. I suppose that inside this method you have some method on, what I name otherStuff, which calls a method that returns `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`, which is what you want to mock.

It would be really better if you insert the `LoginActivity` code to be more precise here, but I hope I helped you.

Comment: If we use robolectric library we won't get null.

Comment: As far as I know roboletric is a kind of unit testing API for UI stuffs and so on, isn't it? Anyway, your runner at this moment was mockito and, if you mock something you dont go inside real method logic.

Comment: Because of mockito runner I was getting Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS as null. Because do not create mock of subclasses used in calling class. For this, we need roboletric